# Apache POI copy XWPFChart in Word Document

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am manipulating Word document templates via the Apache POI Java library. I have one Chart template, let's say a simple bar chart (XWPFChart object). I want to duplicate this XWPFChart, so the user sees two of the same charts in the Word file. Is there an easy way to achieve this, without copying the whole structure one by one? I can't find any clone method for these type of charts...

Comment: You can check whether there can be "an easy way to achieve this". Simply unzip the `*.docx`. You will see the chart is referenced from `/word/document.xml` by `<c:chart r:id="rIdN"/>`. Which chart is referenced from `rIdN` is stored in `/word/_rels/document.xml.rels`. The chart itself is stored in `/word/charts/chartN.xml`. But the chart data is stored in `/word/embeddings/Microsoft_Excel_WorksheetN.xlsx` which is referenced from the chart through `/word/charts/_rels/chartN.xml.rels`.

Comment: So while copying the chart itself needs to be copied to `/word/charts/chartM.xml` together with it's data to `/word/embeddings/Microsoft_Excel_WorksheetM.xlsx`. And all references to those new document parts also needs to be created in `/word/document.xml` - `<c:chart r:id="rIdM"/>` - `/word/_rels/document.xml.rels` and in `/word/charts/_rels/chartM.xml.rels`. Easy? No, the opposite of that.